# Django permissions for GET, PUT and DELETE

Tags: django

I am trying to make the PUT and DELETE methods require authentication but I want the GET method to be public. I know I can take the GET method out and put it into its own function but I would need to make another url for it. What would be the best way to approach this? thanks

```
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def getOrUpdateOrDeleteCar(request, pk):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        vehicle = Car.objects.get(id=pk)
        serializer = CarSerializer(vehicle, many=False)

        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        data = request.data
        car = Car.objects.get(id=pk)

        car.image=data['image']
        car.make=data['make']
        car.prototype=data['prototype']
        car.year=data['year']
        car.serviceInterval=data['serviceInterval']
        car.seats=data['seats']
        car.color=data['color']
        car.vin=data['vin']
        car.currentMileage=data['currentMileage']

        car.save()

        serializer = CarSerializer(car, many=False)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        car = Car.objects.get(id=pk)
        car.delete()
        return Response('Car Deleted!')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a custom permission class:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission

class CarPermission(BasePermission):
    
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return True
        return bool(request.user and request.user.is_authenticated)
```

And use it in your API:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
@permission_classes([CarPermission])
def getOrUpdateOrDeleteCar(request, pk):
...
```